# Router only allows to reserve 16 static IPs. How to reserve more?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dd-wrt

I have a Huawei HG8245X6-10 router, given to me by my provider. All is fine, except that it can only reserve up to 16 static IPs. Since I have a couple of servers and many IoT devices, I need more.

I am trying to avoid using a server as a DHCP server, since I consider it as a more probable point of failure (my servers run on an intel NUC), in comparison to the router. I also want to avoid assigning a static IP to each device, as I prefer reserving the IPs from the router, and some of my devices do not have such option.

Now, my question is: Is it possible to plug in another router, which will only act as a DHCP server on the same subnet? I have never used DD-WRT, and I can't seem to find if it's possible to plug such a router in, use it as a DHCP server, but keep the Huawei as the default gateway for all devices.

Comment: Does your router allow DHCP reservation? That may assist

Comment: Yes, only for 16 devices, but I need more.

Comment: “I have a Huawei HG8245X6-10 router, given to me by my provider.” You need to get a better router and set this one to bridge mode. ISP provided routers typically are limited; no way around it other than to get your own router.

Comment: depending on the purpose of the provided router, you may not even have to use it at all, just drop in a router of your choice - i.e. does your provider require you to use their equipment?

Comment: Yes they do require.

Comment: Get your own router and connect it to your ISP device. You shouldn't have to change anything on your ISP router: just make sure the new device has its own DHCP server that meets your needs. The ISP router will be an upstream device, and all your own internal network stuff will be handled by the new device. You're basically adding 1 step to your external network traffic, but that shouldn't be a problem. It's how I have always run my own internet.

Comment: Yes @music2myear. That is actually the first solution I have thought. But I am trying to avoid adding devices between my end devices and the internet, in order to keep the internet speed as high as possible. I have a solution with OpenWRT I will give a try tomorrow and I will post it for anyone interested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, my question is: Is it possible to plug in another router, which
> will only act as a DHCP server on the same subnet?

Yes, but you can only have 1 DHCP server per subnet.

Virtually every modern router that has a web GUI has a built-in DHCP server.

On top of that you could get a SOC like a raspberry Pi 4 to run a DHCP server.  The linux dhcp server, isc-dhcp-server on raspberry Pi, has a config file which you reserve IP (local IP 192.168.x.x or etc) for specific devices and you can enter as many devices as you want.

At least where I am ISP charge money for static IP, and you want more you have to pay more per month.  The more you want the more crazy the pricing will be.  Since there are a fixed number of IPv4, and they are in shortage ISP maybe give you some free but charge after that.

Now if your ISP is using IPv6, then getting more shouldn't be too big of an issue.

The gateway is usually configured through the routers web GUI.  However, the local DHCP server usually uses 192.168.x.x or another reserved IP.  Reserved IP will not route on the internet.  Usually the device that has the DHCP is the gateway for the devices on the DHCP server.  Then the device gets an IP ,gateway, and etc from your ISP, and routes traffic to it.  On a linux device you have to enable the feature, but should be handle by an router automatically.

Note:  Hopefully your router has a firewall exposing your IoT directly to the internet is terrible idea for security.  Should they ever break through they can mess with all your IoT devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found a possible solution using OpenWRT. I will disable the ISP router's DHCP, and use the OpenWRT router as a DHCP only. There is a setting  with which it can advertise the ISP router as a default gateway and DNS. Regarding security, that's a big concern. For now all devices work local only, and are accessible only through VPN. I am still building the whole thing, and I will reconsider all my security. Thank you for your time.